# removeclass addclass multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a function that works fine, but being new to jquery, I'd like to know if there's a more cleaner way of writting it. Anything advice would help, just trying to learn!

Thanks!

CODE:

```
function displayContent() {
  var $link1 = $('.row.nav li a.bio');
  var $link2 = $('.row.nav li a.stylist');
  var $link3 = $('.row.nav li a.contact');
  var $content = $('#text-content')
  var $bio = $("#bio");
  var $stylist = $("#stylist");
  var $contact = $("#contact");
  var $overlay = $('.content-overlay');

  //link1
  $link1.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $link2.removeClass('active');
    $link3.removeClass('active');
    $link1.addClass('active');
    $contact.hide();
    $stylist.hide();
    $bio.fadeIn(700);
    $overlay.show();
  });
  //link2
  $link2.click(function (e) {
   //same code here
  });
  //link3
  $link3.click(function (e) {
    //same code here
  });


  //close overlay/hide content
  $('html').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $link1.removeClass('active');
    $link2.removeClass('active');
    $link3.removeClass('active');
    $bio.fadeOut();
    $stylist.fadeOut();
    $overlay.fadeOut();
    $contact.fadeOut();
  });

}
```

UPDATE:

HTML MARKUP:

```
    <div class="main-nav pull-left">
  <ul class="row nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="bio">bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="stylist">stylist</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="contact">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
    <section id="text-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="bio" style="display: none;">
content here
</div>
    <div id="stylist" style="display: none;">
content here
</div>
    <div id="contact" style="display: none;">
content here
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('.row.nav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.row.nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var cls = $(this).prop('class');
    $('#' + cls).fadeIn(700).siblings('div').hide();
    $('.content-overlay').show();
});

$('html').click(function () {
    $('.row.nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $("#bio, #stylist, #contact, .content-overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

---

You need to change the order here a little bit which get the class before you add class `active` for your anchor:

```
$('.row.nav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var cls = $(this).prop('class');
    $('#' + cls).fadeIn(700).siblings('div').hide();
    $('.content-overlay').show();
    $('.row.nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('html').click(function () {
    $('.row.nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $("#bio, #stylist, #contact, .content-overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ty8fF/)**

Comment: thanks for the speedy response! this works, except the content isn't showing up? do I have to change the 'class' to id in this line of code >>> var cls = $(this).prop('class'); since its using id's?

Comment: Can you show your sample HTML markup?

Comment: I think it must be attr not prop

Comment: @Felix - added the html markup

Comment: It means to remove class `active` from all the anchors and add only that `active` class to the clicked anchor

Answer (score 2):

Where your HTML is currently like this:

```
<a class="bio">
<a class="contact">
<a class="stylist">

<div id="#bio">
<div id="#contact">
<div id="#stylist">
```

You could change it to this:

```
<a class="tab" data-pane="#bio">
<a class="tab" data-pane="#contact">
<a class="tab" data-pane="#stylist">

<div class="pane" id="#bio">
<div class="pane" id="#contact">
<div class="pane" id="#stylist">
```

Note that each link element has the same class, as does each content div. Also, each link has a `data-` attribute that ties it to a content div.

Then the code can be like this:

```
var $tabs = $('.tab'),
    $panes = $('.pane'),
    $overlay = $('.content-overlay');

$tabs.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $tab = $(this);
    $tabs.removeClass('active');
    $tab.addClass('active');
    $panes.hide();
    $($tab.attr('data-pane')).fadeIn(700);
    $overlay.show();
});

$(document.body).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $tabs.removeClass('active');
    $panes.fadeOut();
    $overlay.fadeOut();
});
```

With the code above, you could add more panes and more tabs and not have to change the JavaScript code.

Note: I used the terms "tab" and "pane", but you can use whatever you want.